# Only let a certain group display page

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a certain page viewable only to a certain group of a database. My SQL table is set up as:

Table: DD_users
Columns: id | group | username | paraphrase | guild | level | salt

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session
require("common.php");

// At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not
if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page.
    header("Location: /DD/index.php");

    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it,
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in.
    die("Redirecting to /DD/index.php");
}

if($_SESSION['user']['group'] == '0')
{
    // Destroy the session to make them log in again.
    unset($_SESSION['user']);

    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page.
    header("Location: /DD/index.php");

    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it,
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in.
    die("Redirecting to /DD/index.php");
}

// Everything below this point in the file is secured by the login system
```

When I try this, will let any user group (0, 1, and 2) access the page when I only want groups 1 and 2 to access the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working another way:

```
require('common.php');
$charname = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
$query = "SELECT adminaccess, guild, username, class, level, active, canRegister, canNews, canActive 
      FROM DD_users 
      WHERE username = ?";
try
{
// These two statements run the query against your database table.
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($charname));
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
// Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
// It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

//print_r($rows);
$group = $rows['0']['adminaccess'];
$guild = $rows['0']['guild'];
$username = $rows['0']['username'];
$class = $rows['0']['class'];
$level = $rows['0']['level'];
$accessAdmin = $rows['0']['adminaccess'];
$canRegister = $rows['0']['canRegister'];
$canNews = $rows['0']['canNews'];
$canActive = $rows['0']['canActive'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any code to check if they are in groups 1 or 2. Just wrap the code around an `if`.

```
if($_SESSION['group'] == '1' || $_SESSION['group'] == '2')
```

Also make sure $_SESSION['group'] is set using `isset`. If it is not set then the last `if` will fail.

Comment: I have it checking for group 0 which is the one I want it to log out if they try to access the page. I they are in groups 1 or 2, that 2nd if statement should return false and continue with the rest of the page.

Comment: I have `print_r($_SESSION);` set and it is only returning id and username in the user array. I put `$_SESSION['user'] = $row;` in my login file. That should set all of my rows in the array, should it not?

Comment: $_SESSION['user'] will then contain an array. Setting it like that wont set $_SESSION['group']. You either need to set group in the session explicitly or get it from the array in session. You can set the user array in session to a variable and then you can access all the values in it from the variable.

Comment: How would I go about setting it to the session? There are a few times I plan on setting up restricted access based on the group number. I got the login system from _[this link](http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-and-stickies-167/how-to-program-a-basic-but-secure-login-system-using-891201.html)_ and modified off of that.

Comment: You set the row you got from the database to a session. The row is already an array so you dont have to worry about making it one. then you can just set the session variable to an array. It is same as $a = $b; then you can access that array values with the same key from the db row.

Comment: How would I go about that? I am looking through the coding to see what is giving me the [user] array but I can not find how it is set. I apologize as I am pretty new to PHP and MySQL.